# C how do I right align string and float

Tags: c, printf

So im getting left alignment right now with `%-<width>s` and `%-<width>.<decimal places desired>`

But what if i want to right align?

The table im getting now is:

```
DAY   MONTH   YEAR   LAT      LONG
01    09      2020   123.4    113.31
```

Comment: please show the code

Comment: The `-` in your format string dictates left alignment... try removing it. See [man 3 printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Comment: by default (this is, not using `-` in front of format specifier --like `%3d` instead of `%-3d`) you get right alignment.  But you need to specify the length of the field, or you will get _as short as possible_ alignment (which is always left)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the minus in your format statement.

`%<width>s`

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf("%15s %5d %5.2f 0x%08X\n", "hello", 42, 3.14, 0xDEAD);
        return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Chris@DESKTOP-BCMC1RF ~
$ ./main.exe
          hello    42  3.14 0x0000DEAD
```